# set multiple values in one variable with different datatypes

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
var result = 0

 func btnPressed(sender:UIButton!)
{
    var btn = sender.titleForState(.Normal)

    var value = btn!

        result += value
        println(result);
}
```

my result variable is an int, and my value variable is an uint8.

What i want to to is each time you press on the button set the title (this is an number) in the result variable. Now i get the error: int is not identical to uint8.
but my result must be an int, how can i solve this?

if i convert the value variable with this:

```
var value = Int(btn)
```

I get the following error: cannot invoke init with an argument of list type @lvalue string?

I don't know how to solve this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Your value variable is not an Int so why do you say it is? It is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is cast the button title to int, so you can then add it to the result variable, like this:

```
var result = 0

func btnPressed(sender:UIButton!)
{
    var btn = sender.titleForState(.Normal)

    var value = btn?.toInt()

    result += value!
    println(result);
}
```